# Author Link is given using authblk style file

Tags: links

I am using authblk.sty file. Each author have a separate link. Below mentioned coding structure is using my client requirement.

```
\author[1,link={http://Junli/people/u/41922}]{Junli Liu}
```

I am unable to design tex file coding this way. But currently i am using below mentioned code. But this coding is not fulfill my client needs. Kindly provide the logic for above mentioned coding

```
\author[1]{\href{http://Junli/people/u/41922}{Junli Liu}}
```

Comment: I don't understand this question (maybe it's just me). Could you try to reword things so that it makes sense what you're after exactly? I'm not sure I understand what is a requirement, what is requested, and what is actually being used/needed (from you or some client).

Comment: A minimal working example would be helpful here. (Probably essential.)